# How do i make a CSS flexbox row to not take the entire width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 4 images that i want to layout 2 by 2 but I don't want each image taking 50% of the screen as that will make it look bad. What do I do?

I tried things like setting the flex-direction to column but I realised that it just made everything in one line with no room to place other images across it.

Comment: Have you ever tried anything ? Can you put your code here by editing your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a max-width to the main container, something like this.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.grid2x2 {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid2x2 > div {
  display: flex; 
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);  
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid2x2 > div > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box { margin: 20px; }
.box1 { background-color: red; }
.box2 { background-color: orange; }
.box3 { background-color: purple; }
.box4 { background-color: grey; }
```

```html
        <div class="grid2x2">
  <div class="box box1"><div>image one</div></div>
  <div class="box box2"><div>image two</div></div>
  <div class="box box3"><div>image three</div></div>
  <div class="box box4"><div>image four</div></div>
</div>
```